# Historical price of various cryptocurrencies

Tags: altcoin

I am currently in need of the historical prices of bitcoin and various altcoins for a project I am working on, but I am only able to find historical prices back to around December 2015 using http://alt19.com/.

I have googled till my eyes bled, but I am unable to find any, does anyone know if some of the major exchanges offer historical prices etc? Preferably at least daily prices.